# Fragment is not getting displayed on clicking the menu item in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer in which I have plenty of Menu Items. I have made a fragment "Home" and then on clicking on the Home menu item the Home Fragment should open.But it's not opening.

My java code is:

```
package com.example.hsports.weddingplanner.Activities;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.hsports.weddingplanner.Fragments.Home;
import com.example.hsports.weddingplanner.R;



public class FrontPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String nameOnTitleBar[];
    int indexSelected=0;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        nameOnTitleBar=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_list_items);

        setupNavigationView();



    }

    private void setupNavigationView() {


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                switch(item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.Home:
                        indexSelected=0;
                        markTheItemSelected(indexSelected);
                        changeNameofTitleBar(indexSelected);
                        fragmentTodisplay(indexSelected);
                        break;

                    case R.id.SignIn:
                        indexSelected=1;
                        markTheItemSelected(indexSelected);
                        changeNameofTitleBar(indexSelected);
                        fragmentTodisplay(indexSelected);
                        break;

                    case R.id.SignOut:
                        indexSelected=2;
                        markTheItemSelected(indexSelected);
                        changeNameofTitleBar(indexSelected);
                        fragmentTodisplay(indexSelected);
                        break;

                    case R.id.AboutUs:
                        indexSelected=3;
                        markTheItemSelected(indexSelected);
                        changeNameofTitleBar(indexSelected);
                        fragmentTodisplay(indexSelected);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ContactUs:
                        indexSelected=4;
                        markTheItemSelected(indexSelected);
                        changeNameofTitleBar(indexSelected);
                        fragmentTodisplay(indexSelected);
                        break;

                }

                drawer.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private void fragmentTodisplay(int indexSelected) {

        switch (indexSelected)
        {
            case 0:
                Home obj=new Home();
                FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.frame,obj,"HOME");
                transaction.commit();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void markTheItemSelected(int indexSelected) {

        navigationView.setCheckedItem(indexSelected);
    }

    private void changeNameofTitleBar(int indexSelected) {

        toolbar.setTitle(nameOnTitleBar[indexSelected]);
    }

}
```

And the fragment code is as follows:
Home.java

```
package com.example.hsports.weddingplanner.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.hsports.weddingplanner.R;

/**
 * Created by I324671 on 11/27/2016.
 */
public class Home extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentaboutus,container,false);

    }
}
```

my navoigation_drawer.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        >


        <item
            android:id="@+id/Home"
            android:title="HOME"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/SignIn"
            android:title="SIGN-IN"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/SignOut"
            android:title="SIGN-OUT"
            />

        </group>

<item android:title="OTHER">

    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
            android:title="ABOUT US"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/ContactUs"
            android:title="CONTACT US"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Share"
            android:title="SHARE"
            />
    </menu>

</item>
</menu>
```

fragmentaboutus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Home"


        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I click on Home icon in the navigation drawer the particular Home fragment doesn't gets displayed.

This is app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:background="@color/blue"

            >



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frame"

            ></FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity_front_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"

        ></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Few questions:
Is R.layout.fragmentaboutus the correct xml for Home fragment?
Do you have any logcat exceptions? 
Is the fragmentTodisplay method triggered?
Is the titlebar title changing?

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted the fragmentaboutus.xml. And yes it is changing the titlebar title. and there is no logcat exceptions.

Comment: Show the xml where R.id.frame is .

Comment: have inserted the xml file which include Framelayout

Comment: Where do app_bar_main.xml en activity_front_page.xml come together?

Comment: I have added the activity_front_page.xml file to the question, please have a look

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem but it works fine for me. Are you sure FrontPage is the activity being shown? Or perhaps the text and the background are blending together? Give the fragment a background color.

Comment: Yeah the textView was getting hidden behind the TitleBar.And the textColor was black.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
transaction.add(R.id.frame, obj, "HOME");
```

with

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frame, obj, "HOME");
```

Comment: Also make sure that R.id.frame refers to a FrameLayout.

Comment: I have inserted the xml file which include Framelayout